# Two inconsistent hashes from same input text file in Perl

Tags: perl, text, hash

I've created a hash that lists each unique word from a text file and the number of times each word appears. The resulting output from this hash indicates it has read the entire file correctly.

However, later efforts to parse text from the same file appear to only capture some of the contents.

For illustrative purposes, a second hash designed to capture each word from the infile as a hash value and that word's relative ordering in the document as the hash key captures only a small fraction of all the words in the document.

Any insights as to the cause of this phenomenon?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $path = "U:/Perl";
chdir($path) or die "Cant chdir to $path $!";

# Starting off computing a simple word count for each word in the 10-K.

my %hash;
my $word;
my %words;

while (<>) {
   my @words = split;

   # Here creating an index of each word in the 10-K and the number of times
   # it appears. This hash works correctly.

   foreach my $i (0 .. $#words) {
      my $word = $words[$i];
      ++$hash{$word};

      # Here trying to create a hash where each word from the infile is a value,
      # and the word's order in the doc is the key.

      $words{$i} = $word;
   }
}

# The code below simply sorts each hash and prints it to an external file.

my @keys = sort { "\L$a" <=> "\L$b" } keys %words;

open(my $fh2, '>', 'report2.txt');
foreach (@keys) {
   print $fh2 "$_ \t $words{$_}\n ";
}
close $fh2;

@keys = sort {
   "\L$hash{$a}" <=> "\L$hash{$b}" or
   "\L$a"        cmp "\L$b"
} keys %hash;

open(my $fh3, '>', 'report3.txt');
foreach (@keys) {
   print $fh3 "$_ \t $hash{$_}\n ";
}
close $fh3;
```

Comment: My guess would be: You're not chomping the lines as you go, so some words will include a `\n`.

Comment: @Sobrique `split` with default args should tidy that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're talking about the `%words` hash? You are keying that hash by the position of each word on each line, so it will only ever have as many entries as the longest line in the file has words.

When processing this data

```
a b c d e f
g h i j k
l m n o
p q r
s t
u
```

your program will build `%hash` with 21 elements, with the keys `a` to `u` and all the values equal to 1 as they are all different.

But the hash `%words` will have six elements -- the number of words in the longest line -- and the values will be overwritten by the *last* word at that position in the line. So your hash will look like

```
{ 0 => 'u', 1 => 't', 2 => 'r', 3 => 'o', 4 => 'k', 5 => 'f' }
```

as the last word in the first position on the line is `u`, the last one in the second position is `t`, etc.

Surely you don't want a hash indexing the words across the whole file? That would be an *array*!

---

**Update**

Thank you for explaining your intention. I don't think putting all the words from the file into a hash one by one is going to help you to count all the unique six-word sequences.

In any case, using numeric keys from `1` to `N`, where `N` is the number of words in the file, is misusing a hash, and as I intimated above what you really want is an array that is *meant* to be indexed by integers.

I think you should keep an array that holds the current six-word sequence. If you add each word to the end of the array and drop them from the beginning then it will always hold the most recent six words from the file.

Something like this, perhaps

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sequence;
my %sequences;

while (<DATA>) {
   for (split) {
     push @sequence, $_;
     if (@sequence >= 6) {
        shift @sequence while @sequence > 6;
        ++$sequences{"@sequence"};
     }
   }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%sequences;

__DATA__
a b c d e f
g h i j k
l m n o
p q r
s t
u
```

**output**

```
{
  "a b c d e f" => 1,
  "b c d e f g" => 1,
  "c d e f g h" => 1,
  "d e f g h i" => 1,
  "e f g h i j" => 1,
  "f g h i j k" => 1,
  "g h i j k l" => 1,
  "h i j k l m" => 1,
  "i j k l m n" => 1,
  "j k l m n o" => 1,
  "k l m n o p" => 1,
  "l m n o p q" => 1,
  "m n o p q r" => 1,
  "n o p q r s" => 1,
  "o p q r s t" => 1,
  "p q r s t u" => 1,
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've correctly diagnosed the problem--I'm indexing %words only over the words in each line rather than all the words in each file.  The larger issue I'm trying to solve is that I'm trying to identify each unique six-word sequence in a large text file, but the resulting array (where each six-word sequence is an element) captures only a small fraction of the text from the file.  I think it has to do with my indexing problem.  How do I index across the entire file instead of just line by line?

Comment: If you want to keep a list of all the words in the file then you should just `push @words, split while <>`. A hash is the wrong choice. I've suggested a solution above that doesn't waste space by keeping the wole file in memory.

Comment: I was able to tweak Borodin's updated code to produce the exact result I was looking for.  I ended up with an output file containing each six-word sequence and the number of times each one appears.  Outstanding!

Comment: @Rick: What did you need to change? I would have thought my code should work out of the box. Except, of course, that it doesn't read from or print to external files.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Borodin's code worked out of the box perfectly, which I only added to in order to get the output in a format that I wanted. I wasn't familiar with the use Data::Dump command or the one below it and didn't end up using them. Thanks!